# Git: overwrite or wipe large files (archives) from repository?

Tags: git, archive

I have a repository that uses 3rd-party code that currently is downloaded and compiled using a shell script. This works, but sometimes mirrors are slow or unreachable. It would be easier for me (since 3rd-party code are only OpenSource projects) to bundle it with my code.

However, I do not want my git repository to become huge over time (like it normally does, when you include large binary files that get stored each time you update them).

Is there any way to wipe .tar.gz (or similar) archives from a git repository?

Or could I somehow overwrite `foo.tar.gz` once it gets outdated? So that it only consumes the memory the most recent version uses (and therefore drops older revisions of the file)?

Comment: Check this https://git-lfs.github.com/

Comment: Here's the official [github doc](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/) about handling large files

Answer (score 0):

> > Is there any way to wipe .tar.gz (or similar) archives from a git repository?

### ***`How to remove big files from the repository`***

There are few ways to do it:

- You can use `git filter-branch`.
- **[BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)**

  > #### ***`BFG Repo-Cleaner`***
  >
  > An alternative to git-filter-branch.
  >
  > The BFG is a simpler, faster alternative to git-filter-branch for cleansing   **bad data** out of your Git repository history:
  >
  > *Removing Crazy Big Files*
  >   *Removing Passwords, Credentials & other Private data*

  #### Examples (from the official site)

  > In all these examples bfg is an alias for java -jar bfg.jar.

  ```
   # Delete all files named 'id_rsa' or 'id_dsa' :
   bfg --delete-files id_{dsa,rsa}  my-repo.git
  ```
- **[GIT LFS (large file storage)](https://git-lfs.github.com/)**

  ---

  ### [image]